# Is there any chance to sign Windows EXE file with digital certificate under FreeBSD?

Tags: code-signing, freebsd

I have a website running on FreeBSD server. Users can visit this website and download my windows application from there. I want to automate the signing process and want to sign it right on the server. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that program that you need, [signtool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), is only available for Windows. You might try if it runs under [wine](http://www.winehq.org/).